# Frequent Kernel Panics, how to solve?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-panic

I have a HP Laptop, with the following configuration:

```
Intel i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40 GHz
NVidia GeForce 940M
Intel HD Graphics 5500
8GB Ram
```

I installed Manjaro i3 on it, and am getting frequent Kernel Panics on it.

**What happens:** While using it, the caps-lock light starts blinking and the computer freezes. Sometimes it doesn't happen for hours, and sometimes it happens on login. After Googling it, I started to debug it myself.

[Here's my `journalctl` logs from recent 2 crashes.](https://pastebin.com/912X9fHX)

Comment: AFAICS, there is no panic - I guess it just freezes? Have you tried pinging it from another machine? Have you tried to ssh into it from another machine? You 'll need to install sshd for that. Have you tried booting a different distro (from DVD or USB thumb drive - no need to install on the hard disk just to test)?

Comment: @NickD shifted from Ubuntu, 3 months ago. It also used to do the same thing. I shifted to Manjaro in hopes of fixing it. The only positive thing is that Manjaro boots faster.
I have ssh setup already, I will give it a try and update here

Comment: @NickD I tried connecting it through SSH, but it didn't work. Also, the laptop restarted after 10 seconds